# Least Square Estimator Derivation for 2-Dimensional Stochastic Process

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, parameter-estimation, least-squares

I am trying to work through an example in this paper [Least squares estimators for discretely observed
stochastic processes](http://math.fau.edu/long/LSS2012JMVA.pdf)

The authors give the following

$$
 \Psi_{n,\epsilon}(\theta) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\lvert X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}-b(X_{t_{k-1}},\theta)\Delta_{t_{k-1}}\rvert^2}{\epsilon^2\Delta_{t_{k-1}}}
$$
of which minimizing gives the Least Square Estimator.

The example I am working through is as follows:

[image: Example 2.9]

The authors state after some basic calculations they achieve the LSE; however, it doesn't seem so basic. If I try to write out $\Psi_{n,\epsilon}(\theta)$ in this case, then it becomes very messy quickly. Also, the matrix $\Lambda_n$ is not invertible, nor is it clear to me where they got that from. So I must be missing something as I assume the example is indeed correct.

Would appreciate if someone would enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $B^T=[C,A],\,\tilde{y}=[1,y^{(1)},y^{(2)}]^T$. Note, for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$
$$\begin{aligned}|x-(C+Ay)n^{-1}|^2&=|x-B^T\tilde{y}n^{-1}|^2=\\
&=x^Tx-2x^TB^Tyn^{-1}+\tilde{y}^TBB^T\tilde{y}n^{-2}\end{aligned}$$
and by linearity
$$\varepsilon^{-2}n\sum_{k\leq n}|x_k-(C+Ay_k)n^{-1}|^2=\varepsilon^{-2}n\sum_{k\leq n}x_k^Tx_k-2\varepsilon^{-2}\sum_{k\leq n}x_k^TB^T\tilde{y}_k+\varepsilon^{-2}n^{-1}\sum_{k\leq n}\tilde{y}^T_kBB^T\tilde{y}_k$$
take the derivative wrt to $B$ and set to $0$:
$$-2\sum_{k\leq n}\tilde{y}_kx_k^T+2n^{-1}\bigg(\sum_{k\leq n}\tilde{y}_k\tilde{y}^T_k\bigg)B=0\implies B=\bigg(\sum_{k\leq n}\tilde{y}_k\tilde{y}_k^T\bigg)^{-1}\bigg(n\sum_{k\leq n}\tilde{y}_kx_k^T\bigg)$$
Now note
$$\tilde{y}_k\tilde{y}_k^T=\begin{bmatrix}1&y^{(1)}_k&y^{(2)}_k\\
y^{(1)}_k&(y_k^{(1)})^2&y_k^{(1)}y_k^{(2)}\\
y^{(2)}_k&y_k^{(1)}y_k^{(2)}&(y_k^{(2)})^2
\end{bmatrix},\,\tilde{y}_kx_k^T=
\begin{bmatrix}x^{(1)}_k&x^{(2)}_k\\
x^{(1)}_ky^{(1)}_k&x^{(2)}_ky_k^{(1)}\\
x^{(1)}_ky^{(2)}_k&x^{(2)}_ky_k^{(2)}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Just to clear up a few things. 1) Your $\Lambda_n$ is made up of entries $\sum_{k\le n}\tilde{y}^{(i)}_k$ and theirs is $\sum_{k\le n}x^{(i)}_{k-1}$ for $i = 1,2$.  Am I correct the $\Lambda_n = \sum_{k\le n}\tilde{y}_k\tilde{y}_k^T$? 2) Is $\Lambda_n^{-1}$ not the inverse?

Comment: @oliverjones yes I changed notation a bit to lighten indexes, but you can see my $y_k$ corresponds to $X_{t_{k-1}}$ and my $x_k$ to $X_{t_k}-X_{t_{k-1}}=:Y_k$. You are correct about $\Lambda_n$. Its inverse appears in the formula of $B$ above, consistently with what is written in the paper. I think this should be it but tell me if you're not convinced by something. Essentially the 'basic calculation' is tedious matrix calculus which is not really basic in my opinion.

Comment: Okay thank you. I understand now, I was making an algebraic mistake with the inverse. Thank you and yes not so basic of a calculation